How to plot multiple values in the same graph using Jenkins plot plugin?
Say I have this csv file:
Operation Name,Field,Value
OP1,Percentage KPI,81.6
OP2,Percentage KPI,47.81
OP3,Percentage KPI,94.29
OP4,Percentage KPI,80.41
How can I plot all values in a single graph using Jenkins plot plugin?
Currently I am using this code but my plot is blank.
                    plot csvFileName: "${allPlotsFile}.csv",
                        csvSeries: [[displayTableFlag: false, exclusionValues: 'Operation Name, Value', file: "${allPlotsFile}.csv", inclusionFlag: 'INCLUDE_BY_STRING', ]],
                        description: "Averages KPIs", group: "KPIs", style: 'line', numBuilds: '10', title: "${allPlotsFile}", yaxis: 'Percentage'

I would like a (not necessary line) graph that would have on the xaxys each operation name, and on the yaxis each value.
